# Youtube Playlist

Tags: javascript, jsp, youtube

I'm using the below embed code to display youtube playlists:

```html
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwSKkKrUzUk&list=PLdSMQMuTYK4A2e67n5JcmjQQODoRK4S-6"
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But the playlists are not being displaying on page load, the user have to click on a button in order for the playlists to be display.
Is there is any way that will make the playlist appear on page load? by the way my website based on JSP.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @JasonRoman See the edit suggestion. shihab doesn’t know how to format code on this site.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27951400/4290096) question looks like the same but there is no answers.